# Trailhead Links on our SFSE profiles?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, hyperlinks

Hi Stack Exchange Admins!

I am wondering if we can configure custom links to add to our profiles?
I know not if this it possible, of course.

But it might be cool to be able to link out to our active Trailhead profiles, for some validation on trusting who is answering what.

thanks

Comment: Voting to move this to meta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to add custom named links to a Stack Exchange profile, like a designated Trailhead profile link field. However, if you'd like, you can reuse the **Website** link field for a Trailhead profile link.

Alternately, the **About Me** field is a free-text profile and does support Markdown links (I have some in my profile, although not Trailhead!)